# Finding number of Coprime tuples from $1$ to $N$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms, gcd-and-lcm

Given $N$ Integers $A_1,A_2....A_N$, and a function $$F(i,j)=A_i*A_j mod  P$$

$P =599*601$ both of which are prime.

I need to find out the number of integer 4-tuples $(a, b, c, d)$ there are such that $F(a, b), F(c, d)$ are co-prime and  $ 1 ≤ a, b, c, d ≤ N$

I can only think of checking every pair of integers i.e brute force. Is there any way better than this ?

Comment: You say P is a given non-prime number - what is its value?

Comment: Brute forcing (going through every possible solution)is one option, however I think reading up on and applying some concepts & / properties of number theory into code would make it more efficiency and take less time.

Comment: @unseen_rider I didn't thought it would matter but If it matters then its $(599 * 601)$

Comment: Ok thanks. Please update your question with this firstly.

Comment: @unseen_rider Thanks. I did it

Comment: Have you tried to do some programming code for your answer?

Comment: @unseen_rider Not yet. I usually think of algorithm first and then implement it. But I am stuck on algorithm for this !!

Comment: I suggest you start with a brute force algorithm, note it's running time, then research, try other ways, and refine your algorithm.

Comment: @sammy You haven't described what you mean by "brute force".  You said "checking every pair of integers" but there are four integers to check, not two.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for the original version of the question. Some VBA for initial brute force attempt below using N = 1000. This been ran once on a laptop, and took > 15 mins to get to over 4 million for counttuples before process was stopped.

It is expected to take a significant time to run since requires at least $N^2$ calculations - eg probably a few hours for $N=1000$

```
Function Modulo(x as double, y as double, p as double) as Double

Modulo = x * y mod p

End Function
```

Main sub:

```
Public p as Double
Public a as double
Public b as double
Public c as double
Public d as double

Dim N as Long  
Dim dblGcd as Long
Dim mod_result_ab as Long
Dim mod_result_cd as Long
Dim count_tuples as Double
Dim Prime1 as Long
Dim Prime2 as Long
Dim answer1 as Variant

Sub Number_tuples()

N = 1000
Prime1 = 599
Prime2 = 601
P=Prime1*Prime2
Count_tuples=0

For a=1 to N
    For b=1 to N
        Mod_result_ab = modulo(a,b,p)    
        If mod_result_ab = 1 then
        Count_tuples = Count_tuples + N*N
    Else
        For c=1 to N
            For d=1 to N
               if d=1 then
                   count_tuples = count_tuples+1    
               Else
                   Mod_result_cd = modulo(c,d,p)    
                   if mod_result_cd = 1 then
                        count_tuples = count_tuples+1
                   else 
                       DblGcd = WorksheetFunction.Gcd(Arg1:=Mod_result_ab,Arg2:=Mod_result_cd)
                       if DblGcd = 1 then
                           Count_tuples=Count_tuples+1
                       End if
                   End if
               End if
             Next d
        Next c
    End if
Next b
```

Next a

Answer1=Msgbox ("Number of tuples is " & Count_tuples & " for " & N & " integers, for Prime1="&Prime1 & " and Prime2 = " & Prime2)

End Sub

Comment: Thanks, I get the brute force but what about those $N$ integers ? I missed writing those integers after N. Please see the updated the question.

Comment: My code should cater for that, for $N$ up to $1000$

Comment: Thanks. I get that it can work for $N < 1000$ but where should I include those $N$ integers in the brute-force code ?

Comment: At the line "N=1000" for the number of integers you are using

Comment: Suppose $N=4$  and integers are $A_1=10,A_2=100,A_3=1000,A_4=10000$. Can you explain now where these integers are used in code ?

Comment: You have changed your question since I answered it, thus my answer above is only relevant for the initial form of your question. For your revised question, how does $A_1, A_2, .. , A_N$ relate to $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it more efficient

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Here's the question original statement : There are N integers $A_1, A_2,A_3,..., A_N$.

 $Fi,j = A_i × A_j % P$.

 Count no. of integer 4-tuples (a, b, c, d) following these conditions:

   $$ 1 ≤ a, b, c, d ≤ N$$
   $$ gcd(F_(a, b), F_(c, d)) = 1 $$

Comment: Ok update your question with this again please

Comment: I did. I hope the question is more clear now.

Comment: You need to add in this part:  $F(i,j)=A_i×A_j$

Comment: I have edited your question following your additional info - if the edit is accepted within the next few hours, it should show.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following approach for the revised question:

1) Put the list of integers into a 1D array (array1)

2) Get $N$ from the amount of elements in the array.

3) Calculate all non-unique possible values of $F(i,j)$ using array1, and put these into a 1D array (array2).

4) Using array2, derive unique value of $F(i,j)$, and put them into a 1D array (array3).

5) Using array3 and array2, calculate the frequency for each unique $F(i,j)$, and put unique $F(i,j)$ and its frequency into a 2D array (array4).

6) Review contents of array4 to pick up any patterns that can be coded for - to help with the next step. 
Eg For unique $F(i,j)$ with value of $1$, these all have a GCD of $1$ with all other $F(i,j)$ so counting them is easier.

7) Start with counttuples=0. Work out and add countuples for every occurence of $F(i,j)=1$ with another $F(i,j)$

8) For each occurence of $F(i,j)>1$, calculate GCD of that with every other $F(i,j)>1$ using the frequencies. If the GCD=1, then the values are coprime, so increment counttuples by 1.

Note: further efficiencies could be made to step 8) using concepts from number theory.

9) After step 8) is done, show what value of counttuples is to the user

Example - VBA code in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852006/excel-vba-how-to-make-code-more-efficient-and-take-less-time